# Navigator.userAgentData is coming as undefined

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, browser, devops, navigator

When I am trying to console navigator.userAgentData its showing undefined . While I'm trying in my local setup its working but in deployed area url when I'm opening console and checking its showing undefined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This feature is available only in secure contexts (HTTPS), in some or all supporting browsers.

[image]

[source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/userAgentData)

Comment: I am trying in chrome then it should support right, only when i am using that deployed area URL and opening console and printing then only its showing undefined

Comment: @abhishekPatil is the url starting with `https://` ?

Comment: No its starting with http://

Comment: @abhishekPatil thats the reason. it needs to be https for userAgentData to work

Comment: please mark this as the valid answer. thank you

Comment: Then how come its working in local even though address starts with http

Comment: @abhishekPatil localhost is a special address and is handled differently by browsers

Answer (score -1):

by any chance are you using samsung galaxy devices ?  i am also getting the same issue on this device.

instead of this you can leverage navigator.userAgent API.